# How to estimate confidence intervals for LC50

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, dose-response

This is my first question, so I hope the question is properly done (my apologies if it's not...)

I am using a binomial GLM model (logit) for some toxicology data investigating the effects of a pesticide to some organisms. The same amount of organisms were exposed to different concentrations of the pesticide and survival was assessed at the end of the experiment. The data and model go as follows:

```
## data:
Concentration <- as.numeric(c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800))
Survival <- as.integer(c(20, 20, 20, 18, 13, 8, 3, 0, 0))
Total <- as.integer(c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20))
Data <- data.frame(Concentration, Survival, Total)
Data$Dead <- Data$Total-Data$Survival
Data$Proport_Surv <- (Data$Total - Data$Dead) / Data$Total

mod <- glm(cbind(Survival, Dead) ~ Concentration, Data, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

This is the summary output:

```
    Call:
    glm(formula = cbind(Survival, Dead) ~ Concentration, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = Data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0156  -0.4775   0.1917   0.4356   0.8721  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    6.992127   1.121066   6.237 4.46e-10 ***
Concentration -0.015196   0.002366  -6.423 1.34e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 163.5934  on 8  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   3.2464  on 7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 19.401

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

An important output in toxicology to infer about the toxicity of any chemical, is to estimate the LC50 value, which is the concentration estimated by the model that elicits 50% mortality. I used the dose.p() function from MASS. For this dataset:

```
library(MASS)
dose.p(mod, p=0.5)
             Dose       SE
p = 0.5: 460.1353 18.16643
```

The LC50 for this pesticide would be 460.1353 but this value should be accompanied by confidence intervals.
My doubt is: How to estimate confidence intervals for an X value? Plotting the model helps to understand what should be my output:

Calculating confidence intervals for the model:

```
NewData1 <- expand.grid(Conc  = seq(0, 800, length = 9))

P_logit <- predict(mod, newdata = NewData1, se = TRUE, type = "link")
NewData1$P_logit <- exp(P_logit$fit) / (1 + exp(P_logit$fit))
NewData1$SeUp <- exp(P_logit$fit + 1.96*P_logit$se.fit) / (1 + exp(P_logit$fit + 1.96*P_logit$se.fit))
NewData1$SeLo <- exp(P_logit$fit - 1.96*P_logit$se.fit) / (1 + exp(P_logit$fit - 1.96*P_logit$se.fit))
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot <- ggplot()
plot <- plot + geom_point(data = Data, aes(y = Proport_Surv, x = Concentration), shape = 1, size = 2.5)
plot <- plot + xlab("Concentration") + ylab("Proportion of surviving organisms")
plot <- plot + theme(text = element_text(size=15)) + theme_bw()
plot <- plot + geom_line(data = NewData1, aes(x = Concentration, y = P_logit), colour = "black")
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(data = NewData1, aes(x = Concentration, ymax = SeUp, ymin = SeLo), alpha = 0.2)
plot <- plot + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, linetype = "dashed")
plot <- plot + annotate("point", x = 460.1353, y = 0.5, size = 3.25, colour = "blue")
plot
```

The blue point annotation is the LC50 estimated by the model. How can I estimate the values where the dashed line intercepts the lower and upper confidence intervals of the model?

Comment: If you have enough computational power, a bootstrap confidence interval might be an option.

Comment: Does the model give better results in estimating the LC50 with both the "zero concentration" and "zero survival" data points removed? I ask as it seems that those two data points are not informative - the "zero survival" concentrations can be very large, and the "zero concentration" is not making a mortality test at all. I'm thinking these two data points might be distorting the regression analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @DavidMoseler, to be honest I am not familiar with bootstrap confidence intervals, so I am still trying to understand how would that allow me to calculate the confidence intervals for the LC50 (concentration that elicits 50% effect, which is in the X axis). Could you please show an example?

Answer (score 1):

The most functional way is to use the tweaking the dose.p function that can be found in Venables, W. N. and Ripley, B. D. (2002) Modern Applied Statistics with S. Springer.

The code below uses the Wald statistic for 95% CI

```
ec = 0.5
library(VGAM)
eta <- logit(ec) 
beta <- coef(mod)[1:2] 
ecx <- (eta - beta[1])/beta[2] 
pd <- -cbind(1, ecx)/beta[2] 
ff = as.matrix(vcov(mod)[1:2,1:2])
se <- sqrt(((pd %*% ff )* pd) %*% c(1, 1))
upper = (ecx+se*1.96)
lower = (ecx-se*1.96)
df1 = data.frame(ecx, lower, upper)


plot <- plot + geom_vline(xintercept = df1$ecx, linetype = "dashed")
plot <- plot + geom_vline(xintercept = df1$lower, linetype = "dashed")
plot <- plot + geom_vline(xintercept = df1$upper, linetype = "dashed")
plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's go back to first principles here to see what you are trying to estimate.  The GLM with the binomial family and the logit link function is just the [logistic regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), so we can use the regression equation for that model.  Letting $p \equiv \mathbb{P}(Y=1)$ be the probability of a positive response outcome (here the death of the organism), your model is based on the model equation:

$$\log \Big( \frac{p}{1-p} \Big) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x.$$

Setting $p = \tfrac{1}{2}$ gives the corresponding explanatory value (here the LC50 concentration):

$$x_* \equiv \frac{\log(\tfrac{1}{2}/\tfrac{1}{2}) - \beta_0}{\beta_1}
= \frac{\log(1) - \beta_0}{\beta_1}
= - \frac{\beta_0}{\beta_1}.$$

So, you are effectively trying to find a confidence interval for the ratio of the true coefficients in the logistic regression.  Usually we approximate the joint distribution of the estimated coefficients by a normal distribution (by appeal to the central limit theorem for large $n$) and so we are then trying to find a confidence interval for the true ratio based on observed estimators that are assumed to be jointly normally distributed around the true values (with non-zero correlation).  (The estimated variance-covariance matrix for the estimators can be found using the `vcov` command on your model.)

The other answer here already shows you how you can use bootstrapping to get a confidence interval in this case, but there are a range of analytic approximations you can use if you prefer; for some examples of analytic forms for this type of confidence interval, see e.g., [Malley (1982)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2287785), [Shanmugalingam (1982)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2987992), and [Dunlap and Silver (1986)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03201412.pdf.).